# How to convert 16 bit PCM data into float in python?

Tags: python, audio, numpy, raspberry-pi, unpack

I'm new to python and Raspberry pi. I'm involved in a project, where I have to embed a bit stream to a wav file. At first I opened the wav file and it is a 2 channel, 16 bit wav file. In order to change the sample values I should convert these sample values into float. I tried a code. But when I run the module, it gives errors as "name struct" isn't defined. And also here I have tried to convert data into integers, since i don't know how to convert into float.If someone can help me to correct this program or suggest another code, then it will be a great help. Thank you.

```
from struct import unpack
import numpy as np
import wave

wavfile = wave.open('/home/pi/desktop/codes/mysong.wav','r')
number_of_frames = wavfile.getnframes()
no_channels = wavfile.getnchannels()
raw_data = wavfile.readframes(number_of_frames)

total_samples = number_of_frames * no_channels
fmt = "%ih" % total_samples
integer_data = struct.unpack(fmt,raw_data)
```

Comment: Did you forget to `import struct`?

Comment: how to do that? do i have to type import struct?But I have included from struct.is it wrong? tell me please

Comment: Either `from foo import bar` then call `bar(...)` or `import foo` and call `foo.bar(...)`, but don't mix and match.

Comment: I have typed from struct import unpack. I don't know much about python. please tell me do I have to include import struct also?

Comment: I didn't understand your suggestion. Please can you correct the code and tell me what is wrong. I'm totally new to these stuff. But  I have a deadline in another week to complete this.

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe said, you either :

```
# if using from ... import ...
from struct import unpack
...
# then change this to
integer_data = unpack(fmt,raw_data)

...

# if using import ...
import struct
...
# then this will work fine
integer_data = struct.unpack(fmt,raw_data)
```

But do not mix & match the imports together.

Comment: Thanx alot..It worked. Thank you. Can u please suggest a way of converting these into float? here I have converted into integer. That's not my original requirement

Comment: @AsanthiAjithSinghUdawatta, I'm not good at wave handling, but I can take look later on. One thing I notice though, you're assigning "%ih" which will be short integers? is that how 16-bit wave normally be handled?